# Shortcut - Add to DL

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, shortcuts, active-directory, distribution-list

I commonly have to add people to a Distribution List using Outlook 2010.  This involves 5 or 6 steps, including having to search for the DL then clicking a few buttons.  Is there a shortcut I can create that will immediately bring up the DL member list, so I can skip the repetitive step of searching for it?  Something I could put on my desktop, pin to the Outlook taskbar icon, or have as an "Quick Step" in Outlook?